# Print append values

Tags: python, numpy

With Python, is there a way to print the last appended line? I want to print/show these values after they are generated/appended. Something like below:

```
Abc = list.append(x)
Print Abc
```

Comment: `append()` returns `None`, if you assign that to `Abc`, it will be `None`

Answer (score 1):

```
print theList[-1]
```

Never name your list `list`, because that's the name of the `list` type already.  See how confusing it is?

Comment: Awesome thanks. RE: list, just used for example.  How would I go about printing certain variables from the list? IE: say value 4 of 8

Comment: And if I wanted to show the 4th last value appended I would go "print TheList[-3]" ?

Comment: The 4th last is `theList[-4]`; Python is 0-based but counting from the end begins with `-1` because there is no `-0` in integers.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, `append()` method going to add an item to end of a list. So if you want to see that, basically you have to print the last item of that list.

```
print (my_list[-1])
```

Also like `list,string`  etc. are reserved by Python. Don't use them when defining variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
>>> print myList[len(myList) - 1]
>>> print myList[-1]
```